# 1980's? Young Adult Fantasy Orphan Son Who Dies in Car Accident

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

I remember reading this short story or novella when I was a teenager, so it may have been written in the 70's, 80's, or 90's. I remember that there is a teenage orphan son who is on a road trip. You find out later that he dies in a car accident, but he is transported to what he thinks is Heaven. His parents are there, and they are at Woodstock. He realizes that he doesn't like his parents, or the music, and that he is in Hell. Does this sound familiar? I haven't been able to find this via Google or Reddit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This rang a faint bell with me, and I was able to localize it to "[Dead End](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?15762)", a short novel in the "Shockers" series by John Peel, published in 1994.

The best, and indeed only, summary I have been able to find is at [tvtropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeadAllAlong):

> a young man buys a 1967 Mustang just like the one his deceased parents
> had. He never got to know them and in the hopes of learning more about
> them, he sets off on a road trip in his new car. Many surreal things
> begin happening, culminating in his arrival at a Woodstock-like music
> festival which he finds out is a part of heaven where deceased
> musicians and hippies go... because he's dead. He was unknowingly
> killed in an accident during his journey and now is where his parents
> have gone. But the problem is, unlike them, he hates '60s music so
> this is torture to him.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I've been looking for this for *years*